# 'l' bit in in file permission ( ---x--l--- )O/P

Tags: c++, unix, solaris

I am getting a l bit in file permission sometimes but not regulaly When i create 
file With `int fd = open("\tmp\lockfile", O_CREAT | O_EXCL);`. The O/P that i get in rare 
scenario  When i do `ll \tmp\locfile` is

```
root@cool> ll lockfile
---x--l---   1 root     nms            0 Feb 21 10:40 lockfile
root@cool>`
```

While most of the time O/P is this :-

```
root@cool> ll importer.lck
----------   1 user  nms            0 Feb 22 10:58 importer.lck`
```

I know creating file through O_CREAT While not providing the mode can be an issue as done 
above can be an issue . In this case:-

```
root@cool> ll lockfile
---x--l---   1 root     nms            0 Feb 21 10:40 lockfile
root@cool>
```

i am not able to delete the lockfile once the process Which created this is over`. 
chmod also does not work in above case but chown seems to work .

How can i prevent creating the file with these permission `---x--l---` is it just by passing mode ? The mask set is :-

```
root@cesme:/tmp# umask
0022
root@cesme:/tmp#`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You omitted the required third parameter of open(), which is mode. (The parameter is required when you use O_CREAT). Since there's no parameter on the stack, open uses a random value (i.e. the return address on the stack).

Answer (score 1):

artensay - No.

```
http://www.tereknor.com/solaris/solfaq/faq174.html
```

The OP was messing with mandatory locking, very incorrectly. You may not have read his other posts.  However that bit got set it was from an ancillary call like an fcntl() statement, not stack garbage.  And yes, you are correct, the open statement was wrong.

Comment: artensay might be wrong in mentioning that it takes it from stack , but i guess the root cause was the way file was created using O_CREAT , i believe providing a mode exclusively will prevent this from happening . What say you ?